# Create tag using Autocomplete material UI when user input anything

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I can type something which shows selected tags from the dropdown list but I want a user can type something and create a tag or multiple tags separated by a comma.

I used a `useState` hook which is an array.

```
const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);
```

I set the `Autocomplete` like the following code -

```js
<Autocomplete
  style={{ margin: "10px 0" }}
  multiple
  id="tags-outlined"
  options={tags}
  defaultValue={[]}
  freeSolo
  renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
    value.map((option, index) => (
      <Chip variant="outlined" label={option} {...getTagProps({ index })} />
    ))
  }
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      label="Tags"
      placeholder="Tags"
      value={tags}
      onChange={(e) => setTags([...tags, e.target.value.split(",")])}
    />
  )}
/>;
```

Comment: The please [edit] the question to contain all relevant information (with correct formatting!) because comments are difficult to read and can easily be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly, I tried for an hour before questioning. But Solve it within a few moments after putting the question.
Here's the solution-

```js
<Autocomplete
  style={{ margin: "10px 0" }}
  multiple
  id="tags-outlined"
  options={tags}
  defaultValue={[...tags]}
  freeSolo
  autoSelect
  onChange={(e) => setTags([...tags, e.target.value])}
renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      label="Tags"
      placeholder="Tags"
      value={tags}
    />
  )}
/>;
```

the output will look like this.
[user input tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPo2s.png)

but I want to add multiple tags that didn't happen right now which can be put via giving a space or comma.

Answer (score 0):

Partly relevant but I think it can be helpful for someone using React Hook Form library with MUI5.

Storing tags in the state would render them being saved in form data when submitted. Instead, you need to use their onChange function.

```
const Tags = ()=>{
    const { control,handleSubmit } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
            checkbox: true,
            autocomplete:["test"]
          }
    });

    const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

    return <>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Controller
                name="autocomplete"
                control={control}
                render={({ field }) => {
                    const {value,onChange} = field
                    return <Autocomplete
                        style={{ margin: "10px 0" }}
                        multiple
                        id="tags-outlined"
                        options={value}
                        defaultValue={[...value]}
                        freeSolo
                        autoSelect
                        onChange={((e)=>onChange([...value,e.target.value]))}
                        renderInput={(params) => {
                            return <TextField
                            {...params}
                            label="Tags"
                            placeholder="Tags"
                            value={value}
                            />
                        }}
                    ></Autocomplete>
                }
            }
            />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </> 
}
```